# Signed certificate is not trusted locally

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a .csr certificate signed by a trusted CA (DigiCert). 
When I create a Tomcat  Connector with this certificate locally and go to `127.0.0.1` then the browser answers the connection is unsecure. The certificate is visible in browser. I expected that browsing `https://127.0.0.1:9000`, I would see the 'green' connection.

Could you please explain how I can test this certificate locally? I want to see the 'green' connection in the browser locally.

Comment: What is the CNAME the certificate is issued on?

Comment: Aris, denasales.com

Comment: Then you have to use the domain name instead of the address. The certificate is issued on this domain, hence when you try to access it via the localhost IP you get the 'insecure connection'. As mentioned in the below answer you can bypass this via adding a new line in your hosts file mapping your localhost IP to the domain the certificate's issued on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your certificate is not signed for 127.0.0.1 but for an FQDN (a domain name such as example.com).

Edit your hosts file (`/etc/hosts` on Linux, on Windows it's `c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`), and add a line corresponding to your certificate's FQDN, such as `127.0.0.1 example.com`

Comment: I'm probably splitting hairs... A FQDN  ends in a dot ("***.***"). It denotes the top of the DNS tree. What you have shown is just a DNS name. The DNS name can have search domains added to them by the resolver. A FQDN will not because it is already at the top of the tree.

Comment: @jww I don't in which RFC it's clearly defined. Appart from certificates, 2396 says "The rightmost
   domain label of a fully qualified domain name will never start with a
   digit, thus syntactically distinguishing domain names from IPv4
   addresses, and may be followed by a single "." if it is necessary to
   distinguish between the complete domain name and any local domain"

Comment: Check W. Richard Stevens [TCP/IP Illustrated](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0201633469). I think WIkipedia even states it, but Stevens is who I would consider the authoritative source.